# Controlling Shapekey with Empty (Appear or Dissapear)

Tags: python, drivers, collections

I'd like to control my expressions with empties.
So I'd like to have 4 empties:

- Laugh
- Sad
- Suprised
- Angry
  These will be in expression collection.
  And when I set the "expression empty" visibility on, it'll create the effect.
  Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're choosing not to do this with Shape Keys?

Comment: I'll be rendering my characters randomly, and my randomization script is working by toggling Render visiblity. But the character has different materials, I'd like to implement the expressions to this randomisation too.
So right now I can randomise the color, the hair with my rigged character.
I need to random the expressions on the way as well, if not, I'm stuck with assigning fixed expressions to certain materials, which I don't really want to.